# Using cin to insert elements to a map in C++

Tags: c++

I have no idea on how to use cin in order to insert data to a map.

I believe it should look something like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<=N;i++){
    mapas.insert ( '/*word from cin*/',i );
    /*or*/
    mapas[/*word from cin*/]=i;
  }
```

Here is my full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main() {

  map<string,int>mapas; 
  map<string,int>::iterator it;
  int N;//how many words there will be
  string zodis;//the word I will be looking for later
  cin>>N;
  cin>>zodis;




  for(it=mapas.begin();it!=mapas.end();it++){
    cout<<it->first<<endl;}

  }
```

Any ideas would be appreciated because Im about to kill myself

Comment: `mapas[zodis] = N;`

Comment: How is `N` words 1 word, unless `N` is always 1? do you mean instead you want to read in `N` pairs of words and numbers? or really only one word and one number?

Answer (score 0):

you need

```
mapas[<string>] = <int>;
```

e.g.,

```
mapas[zodis] = N;
```